# Does SockJS emulate websockets even on a browser that supports websockets?

Tags: javascript, websocket, sockjs

Does SockJS emulate websockets even on a browser that supports websocket or not?

I'm trying to use websocket and RabbitMQ to send and receive messages on the web. RabbitMQ provides a `rabbitmq-web-stomp` plugin which uses Sockjs to bridge the websocket and RabbitMQ STOMP plugin.

But SockJS says it's a websocket emulator. So I want to ask if it will emulate websocket even on a browser that supports websockets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the SockJS javascript library](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client) (emphasis mine):

> SockJS is a browser JavaScript library that provides a WebSocket-like object. SockJS gives you a coherent, cross-browser, Javascript API which creates a low latency, full duplex, cross-domain communication channel between the browser and the web server.
>
> Under the hood **SockJS tries to use native WebSockets first**. If that fails it can use a variety of browser-specific transport protocols and presents them through WebSocket-like abstractions.

SockJS exposes an API like that of the websocket to make your javascript application think you always have a web socket even if you don't. It's easier to write your application with only one transport in mind and let something else emulate it if missing. Your application code is simpler.

SockJS will handle the fallbacks. It will try in order these ways of communications, using the first one that is supported.

```
[
 'websocket',
 'xdr-streaming',
 'xhr-streaming',
 'iframe-eventsource',
 'iframe-htmlfile',
 'xdr-polling',
 'xhr-polling',
 'iframe-xhr-polling',
 'jsonp-polling'
]
```

Notice web socket is first. If your browser supports web sockets SockJS will use that.